# Android intent Intent.ACTION_VIEW is opening the third party app embedded inside the app itself

Tags: android, android-intent

The below code is intended to open a link inside the browser, however in some cases, if the link can be opened by a third-party app, it opens the third-party app instead. There are some cases where the third-party app is being opened embedded inside the app itself. If one goes to multitasking, the third party app can be seen open inside the app itself, and the third party app is not shown there. One suspicion is that the third-party app is a web-based app, however not sure if this is a cause. Any suggestions on what could be causing this?

```
        if(link.getLink() != null && URLUtil.isValidUrl(link.getLink())) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            intent.setData(Uri.parse(link.getLink()));
            startActivity(intent);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

This was resolved by adding the below flag to the intent to make sure that a new task is created, although it is still unknown why this behaviour occurred.

```
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
```